# How to change the security level of a local assembly to internet or customized permission set?

Tags: .net, security, caspol

I built a assembly which is a class library, for example lib.dll .
And I also have a application to access this lib, for example test.exe.

I changed the security permission for the test.exe to "intranet".
At the same time, I want to change lib.dll to "Internet" like this: (Because I want to do some testing for security.)

```
CasPol.exe -m -ag 1.2 -strong -file lib.dll lib 1.0.0.0 Internent
```

But it seems the lib.dll can not get the security permission as I wanted.
What is wrong with the command? Or maybe there are some other better solutions?

Thanks
-Jamebo

Answer (score 0):

Please visit below link which help you to change trust level of local assembly

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815147